# If you need dependency injection, put cucumber-picocontainer on the classpath

Tags: java, automated-tests, cucumber, rest-assured, web-api-testing

Keep getting this error and I am now at my wits end, can anyone explain what I may be doing wrong please - apparently might have to do with cucumber versions, how does one make the versions match:

io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: class stepDefinitions.SearchStepsUser doesn't have an empty constructor. If you need dependency injection, put cucumber-picocontainer on the classpath

**stepDefinition file**

`code`

Comment: Your Cucumber dependencies look a bit mismatched. Both the group and version are inconsistent.

Comment: So my issue is the latest version of pico-container does not work with the other cucumber libraries. So I opted for an older version but I'm getting the error above. How do you match cucumber versions?

Comment: You should ask a question about the latest version not working then. The older  version of cucumber-pico isn't detected at all by latest parts of cucumber. So you now have an XY-problem. https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Thanks issue resolved! The problem was with my runner file, it didn't like the Extent report.

Answer (score 0):

```
io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: class stepDefinitions.SearchStepsUser doesn't have an empty constructor
```

That means that your `SearchStepUser` should not have this constructor:

```
public SearchStepsUser(StepData stepData) {
    this.stepData = stepData;
}
```

You need to remove this constructor. If you need to store `StepData`, create some utility class to store it and provide it during your test step execution. In fact, `StepData` could (should) be this utility class with static methods that could be easily invoked during execution of your tests.

Alternatively, the error message is recommending the use of *picocontainer* if Dependency Injection (what you are doing by passing `StepData` through the constructor) is needed. If you require DI, just search the web for a picocontainer tutorial.